# Android e-commerce Update Cart

Tags: android, e-commerce

I am new to android. I am trying to develop an e commerce application. Till now I have implemented the cart feature using SQLLite database. I want to know how can I update the cart information of the user on the server. any resource will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQLite database is client side. it means store data in your android not in your server. to update on server just make http request from android to server (synchronize)

Comment: Suppose I have lots of item on my cart. how should I pass all item details to the server. It may sound like a stupid question but I am a beginner.

Comment: the easy one is to HTTP post the item one by one to the server. The advance method include you to make a file contain all item then HTTP post the new file using byte stream to read and write